# Scala split string by group x

Tags: regex, string, scala

I'm looking for a way to split a string in Scala by a regular expression with a group.

For example split by a dot which is NOT preceded by a backslash. I tried use

`"[^\\\\]\\."r.split("a.b.c\.d.e)`

But it included the previous string which was not a dot character.

```
Expected: a,b,c,c\.d,e 
Result: , , c\., e
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Regex [negative lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) to exclude matching any `.` with a preceding `\` as follows":

```
val pattern = """(?<!\\)\.""".r

pattern.split("""a.b.c\.d.e""")

// res1: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c\.d, e)
```